# Restart oozie bundle job in killed state

Tags: bundle, oozie, resume

I want to restart an oozie bundle job that is in a killed state.
The bundle job has one coordinator job.
I accidentally killed the coordinator job instead of killing a particular action id.
Due to this the bundle job is also marked as killed.
I tried -rerun on the individual actions on the coordinator job, but no new actions are getting created.
I tried -rerun on the bundle job but don't see any change in the bundle job status. It is still showing as killed.
Please suggest if there is a way to make the bundle job into running again.

Thanks